# Dispute custom review ban

Tags: support, review-suspension

I just reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13971322) by flagging it as blatantly off-topic. However when I tried to do more reviews I saw this message: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40019844/is-non-alcoholic-wine-actually-have-alcohol-in-it was obviously not an on-topic first post.
Come back on Nov 12 at 11:54 to continue reviewing."

This doesn't look like the standard failed review message so I think a moderator banned me. How can I dispute this ban from a moderator or is the message wrong and am I banned for something else I did?

Comment: Too bad the user who asked the question is deleted. The "SPAM" alert is wrong, and it would be nice to point him to the correct forum.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I'll put my paws up and admit to not reading the information presented to me correctly - I'm sorry about that.

I've lifted your review ban.

Comment: What about others that banned incorrectly like this one?

Comment: In three days, my review ban will end for failing an audit on a question which I flagged primarily opinion based. System said it's OK. Now it's closed for the last 20 days.